# Checking if children records will hit database in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there a shorthand way of checking this?

```
item.changed? || item.new_record? || item.marked_for_destruction?
```

Here is some context...

```
class Store
  has_many :items

  before_save :check_if_children_will_save

  def check_if_children_will_save
    items.each do |item|  
      if item.changed? ||
         item.new_record? ||
         item.marked_for_destruction?

         ...do some stuff
      end
    end
  end
end
```

There doesn't seem to be anything in the Rails API docs.

I know I could do a helper method to return a boolean but just checking in case I've missed something built into Rails.

Comment: You could achieve this through a `:before_save` hook on the `Item` model.

Answer (score 0):

Would `item.valid?` help? If it can't be saved that should return false.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  An item may be valid but not be changed, not new and not marked for destruction so this would give false positives to what I'm trying to achieve.